# if condition in Solr Query

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

Can anyone of you please suggest some solution for the following questions?

What is the correct format of if query in solr. 
I want to check if a particular fieldvalue is greater than a constant
For ex:
if((field1>0), field1, field2)
is this possible in solr?
and also can we do the same with date field. by comparing two dates?

Answer (score 1):

Solr ( and Lucene in general) are documents based.
It means the unit of information is a single document ( composed by a set of fields).
You search and you get back documents.
To search for documents that have the value of a field less than a constant you can use range queries[1] :

field1:[* TO 500] 
This is equivalent to " return me all the documents where field1 has a value < than 500.
The same can be done for dates.

Given that, I don't get the "conditional" part of your request, but Solr offers a conditional function query, that could be of use[2]

[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-standard-query-parser.html#TheStandardQueryParser-RangeSearches

[2] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html#FunctionQueries-AvailableFunctions

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to compare two dates. i guess we will not be able to do that with these type of range query.

Comment: What is your information need as a user ?
Return me all the documents that ( date comparation of which kind ? )